# multi tenancy using Spring3

Tags: spring, ftp, sftp, multi-tenant

I am developing a multi-tenancy application using spring 3.0 and have need to upload the download the files into/from FTP server depending upon the tenant. We have different FTP location in the same FTP server for each tenant. Can you please help me how to configure/change the FTP location depending upon the tenant using spring 3.?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You somehow have tenant resolver and/or tenant context. E.g. as described [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hibernate-multitenancy-implementation) or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300264/how-to-fetch-tenant-identifier-stored-in-a-table-of-default-schema)

So all you need is to get tenant identifier - String representing the tenant. Then you can have a Map where key is tenant identifier and values is the required path or organize some logic to get the path from DB by tenant identifier.